# Verifying that $x^{x}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Using the following definition $x=\ln(y)\iff y=e^{x}$ I will show $x^{x}$ is continuous at $(0,\infty)$.

**Attempt** :
We note that $x^{x}=e^{x\ln(x)}$. We have that $x$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and $\ln(x)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$. Thus, $x\ln(x)$ is continuous at $(0,\infty)$. Therefore, the composition $e^{x\ln(x)}$ is continuous at $(0,\infty)$.

Is this proof correct? because I feel like some necessary details are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks good; the only thing I would add is that you also use the fact that $e^x$ is continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$ (you need this for the full range since $x\ln x$ can be negative).

Comment: Ahh you are right but to be precise, would it be better to say $e^{u}$ instead of $e^{x}$?

Comment: @ZeinabQom good point. I think it is ok either way but it is certainly clearer to use $u$.